# How to Setting PDO PHP 7.0 on AWS Server EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, pdo, laravel-5.4, php-7

I have trouble on setting PDO on AWS Server. Like this :

```
[root@ip-172-31-31-52 /]# sudo yum install php-pdo
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                                                | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates                                             | 2.5 kB     00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.3.29-1.8.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.29-1.8.amzn1 for package: php-pdo-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.29-1.8.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php70-common-7.0.33-1.32.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.22-1.98
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php70-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How to solve this. I need PDO settings. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:

Take snapshot of your server

Step 2:
Check your php version and install the php packages corresponding to php version.

Additional info:

- Laravel 5.4 requires PHP >= 5.6.4
- Make sure you install php 5.6.4 or greater.
- Specifically call out the exact package for php version.

Example:

- For PHP 5.6 support, the package is php56-mysqlnd.
- For PHP 7.0 support, the package is php70-mysqlnd.
- For PHP 7.1 support, the package is php71-mysqlnd.

These package will install pdo support.

Advice, Install latest stable version of php and laravel.

Happy coding!

Comment: Im happy it did. :D